# Package Manager Console fails to read ConnectionStrings when running Add-Migration

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, entity-framework-core, connection-string

Running Add-Migration on the Package Manager Console inside Visual Studio 2019 throws a NullReferenceException when trying to access the connectionString key with `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestingDatabase"].ConnectionString`

This is a blank project on Windows. I created a Windows Forms App (.NET Core) and just installed the basic requirements - EntityFrameworkCore, EntityFrameworkCore tools and System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
I manually created an App.config file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestingDatabase" connectionString="myConnectionString"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Running the code in Debug (F5), the command
`Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestingDatabase"].ConnectionString);` gives me `myConnectionString`, which is the expected result.

The same command in the Package Manager Console (during the execution of `Add-Migration InitialMigration`)  throws a `System.NullReferenceException`.
The solution contains a single project, that is set as StartUp Project and is also the Default project in the Package Manager Console.

It seems the Package Manager Console is not properly reading my App.config, although there doesn't seem to be any obvious configuration error, since running the project normally works just fine.
I don't know what could be wrong, so if more info is needed please let me know.

EDIT: This question [.Net Standard 2.0 ConfigurationManager Doesn't Read Connection Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377782/net-standard-2-0-configurationmanager-doesnt-read-connection-strings) was posted yesterday and seems to be a very similar problem to mine.

Comment: Is the database itself created already? Try this command: dotnet ef database update

Comment: The problem happens before the database connection is made. If I use a raw string (optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("myConnectionString");), the connection is made and both the migration and database update works. The problem happens when I use the ConfigurationManager (optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestingDatabase"].ConnectionString);)

Comment: Which version of .net-core are you using?

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169392/ef-core-tools-system-configuration-configurationmanager-assembly-not-found

Comment: I'm using .NET Core 3.0. I also tried with version 2.2 with no success. That question seems related to my problem, but I don't understand the solution. What does adding the "ConfigurationManager to the .Net Framework app" means? In my case, the ConfigurationManager is already a dependency at Dependencies -> NuGet -> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with a workaround. Instead of using App.config, I created a settings.json file and used the Config.NET library to read it. Make sure settings.json is copied to Output Directory.

This does not address the issue of the App.config file being inaccessible by the Package Manager Console, but at least prevents me from hardcoding strings into code.